# How to merge three dataframes based on ID

Tags: r

I have three dataframes. All have an ID number column. How can I merge the three dataframes into one by ID?

I have tried, but the data from "ant_data_session_1" are returned as NA.

```
all_merged_data<- ABM_maindata %>%
  left_join(esm_centralities, by="Rid") %>%
  left_join(ant_data_session_1, by="Rid")
```

Comment: Unfortunately nobody will be able to help unless you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you manually verified that there exists rows (i.e. `Rid` values) in `ant_data_session_1` that also exist in `ABM_maindata`? Remember, with left_join, any rows that exist in `esm_centralities` but not in `ABM_maindata` are left. You might want to consider `full_join` or some other variants of the join-family.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that "Rid" in ABM_maindata was factor and had trailing spaces.

Fixed by importing ABM_maindata with `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` and
`ABM_maindata$Rid <- trimws(ABM_maindata$Rid, which = c("right"))`